# Changing a global var

Tags: javascript

Im trying to change a var value everytime I click a button. But for some reason the var value keeps changing back to 0. Not sure if this is a scope issue?

Trying to update global var curPos to the reqPos value on each click

Please see code below

```
var reqPos = 0,
    curPos = 0;


function viewRotate(curPos, reqPos){

  var curPos = reqPos;
  console.log('1 ' + reqPos + curPos);

  if(curPos === 0 && reqPos === 12) {

    for(var j = 0; j < reqPos; j++){
      curPos++;
    }
    curPos = reqPos;
  }
  else if (curPos === 0 && reqPos === 24) {

    for(var j = 0; j < reqPos; j++){
      curPos++;
    }
    curPos = reqPos;
  }
  else if (curPos === 0 && reqPos === 36) {
    for(var j = 0; j < reqPos; j++){
      curPos++;
    }
    curPos = reqPos;
  }
}

e('.btn-front').click(function(){
    viewRotate(curPos, 0);
    console.log(reqPos);
});

e('.btn-right').click(function(){
    viewRotate(curPos, 12);
    console.log(reqPos);
});

e('.btn-back').click(function(){
    viewRotate(curPos, 24);
    console.log(reqPos);
});

e('.btn-left').click(function(){
    viewRotate(curPos, 36);
    console.log(reqPos);
});
```

Comment: You call the function with `reqPos` equal to zero, and the function never changes `curPos` to any other value.

Comment: It is indeed a scope issue.

Comment: @Hoten yes but it still won't work even if that's fixed; the function sets `curPos` to `reqPos` at the outset, and then again if any of those tests succeed.

Comment: the 'var' is making a new variable. It is masking the outer curPos.

Comment: as well, the method viewRotate's parameters are masking the global variables, too.

Comment: @Pointy if i click .btn-right it transfers a value of 12 to reqPos, so why does it then return to 0 again?

Comment: Have you read the other answers?

Comment: What steps did you take after learning it may be a scope issue? Because this is an egregious violation of scoping, and simply renaming things would have likely solved your issue.

Comment: @Hoten, after trying to get a better understanding of scope and why my script was failing *freakish's* answer did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a matter of shadowing variables:

```
var reqPos = 0,
    curPos = 0;


function viewRotate(curPos, reqPos){
```

At that point you've already lost access to global `curPos` and `reqPos`. Renaming these local variables is one approach.

The other is to actually process the data locally in the function, return it and do the assignment in `click` handler.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed an issue of scope. You are redefining the `curPos` variable within the `viewRotate` function's scope by preceding it with the `var` token. Try the following to perform assignment on the `curPos` that is already defined in `viewRotate`'s 'parent' scope:

```
function viewRotate(reqPos) {
    curPos = reqPos;
    // ...
}
```

Following from this, as pointed out by @PaulRoub, you need to redefine your function signature to remove the `curPos` parameter as primitives are passed-by-value:

```
function viewRotate(reqPos) { /*...*/ }
viewRotate(0); // Now call without `curPos`
```

Comment: That's true, but the function will always just set `curPos` to `reqPos`, those pointless `for` loops notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks @PaulRoub, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You redefined the `curPos` variable within the `viewRotate()` function, which will overshadow the global `curPos` variable in local scope:

```
var reqPos = 0,
    curPos = 0; // <- Defining variable here


function viewRotate(curPos, reqPos){

  var curPos = reqPos; // <- Redefining it here

  ...
```

You should rename or remove the local `curPos` variable from your `viewRotate()` function altogether.

Comment: If you read your code carefully you will realize that it changes nothing.

Comment: @freakish, he wasn't posting revised code. He was pointing out the error.

Comment: @Hoten `You should remove the var keyword in the viewRotate() function.` False, changes nothing. He didn't point out the real error. How is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, he also overlooked the method's parameters. They are both masking. Honestly, that's as far as I looked.

Comment: @freakish: Sorry, you are right. The function's argument will mask as well.

Answer (score 0):

The variable **curPos**, defined outside of your function, is not the same variable as **curPos**, defined inside your function, *even though they have the same name*.

JavaScript separates your global variable **curPos** (outside the function) from your local variable **curPos** (inside your function). Having the same name will not make them the same variable.

To access your global **curPos** from inside your function, remove the "var" keyword, as @sdgluck suggests. Otherwise you end up creating a brand new local variable inside your function that just happens to have the same name as one of your global variables.

But having said that, if all you need to do is

> update global var curPos to the reqPos value on each click

then couldn't you use some simpler code? Such as...

```
var curPos = 0;

function viewRotate( _reqPos ) {
    curPos = _reqPos;
}

e('.btn-front').click(function(){
    viewRotate( 0 );
});

e('.btn-right').click(function(){
    viewRotate( 12 );
});

e('.btn-back').click(function(){
    viewRotate( 24 );
});

e('.btn-left').click(function(){
    viewRotate( 36 );
});
```